# iMessage export to PDF

Tags: macos, ios, messages, archive

I am looking for advice for an iMessage program/app that can export threads with dates/times in conversation style, preferably to PDF.

I have researched this quite a bit, but most results seem gimmicky and I am hesitant without some actually user feedback. Hopefully I can get some feedback here with which program is worthwhile at providing what I need.